# Java Custom Autocomplete for Ace Editor

Tags: ace-editor

I have customized ace to handle Maven Java Projects. Most of the functionalities are working except autocomplete for Classes and Method.

Now I have created a [trie](https://github.com/pujansrt/trie-js) to fill all classes.

```
var trie = new Trie();
trie.insert("java.util.HashTable");
trie.insert("java.util.HashMap");
trie.insert("java.util.HashSet");
```

When I call trie.autoComplete('java.util.H') then it shows all available classes. My ace editor code

```
var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
langTools.addCompleter(javaCompletor);

var javaCompletor = {
   getCompletions: function (editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
        var currline = editor.getSelectionRange().start.row;
        var content = editor.session.getLine(currline);
        let arr = content.split(' ');
        content = arr[arr.length-1];

        callback(null, trie.autoComplete(content).map((a,b)=>{
          return {value: a, score: 1, a: a, meta: '', type: 'snippet'}
        }));
   }
}
```

[image]

---

[image]

But my problem, it is not working quite well. Earlier text is not get replaced. And is it correct way of customizing autocomplete for Ace ?